# Update the some value in object and set to list in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have problem to update the value and set the list.

**StudentEntity.class**

```
public class StudentEntity{
  private String name;
  private int rollNo;
  private String address;
}
```

**Student.class**

```
public class Student{
   private String name;
   private int rollNo;
   private String address;
}
```

Now I will change the address from old data. First,I am getting the data from database.

Map the entity to model class using ObjectMapper.

```
Student student=new Student();
studentEntity=studentRepository.findOne(id);    
student=objectMapper.convertValue(studentEntity, Student.class);
student.setAddress("Bangalore");
List<Student> listOfStudent=new ArrayList();
listOfStudent.add(student);
```

Finally I returned the list of Student. But value is not updated.It showed the old one.

Comment: What value is not updated?

Comment: address is not updated

Comment: Can you share the whole code?

Comment: show your setter - setAddress method. I bet this method does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting studentEntity to StudentEntity again. instead it should be like following.

```
 student = objectMapper.convertValue(studentEntity, Student.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issues is in **objectMapper.convertValue** you have to pass **Student.class** as Second parameter.

`student = objectMapper.convertValue(studentEntity, Student.class);`